# Is it permissible for a Muslim man to marry two women at once?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

Can a Muslim marry two girls at once? I mean, a Man sits and two other girls sit and they are married of at once. Is that allowed in Islam?

This question just came into my mind.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing against it which is written in Quran and Hadeeth. So I believe its allowed.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. I strongly recommend you to read [answer] and by the way to learn more about how this site is supposed to work you may consider taking our [tour] and checking the [help].

Answer (score -3):

Allah Says in Quran,

> "If ye fear that ye shall not be able to deal justly with the orphans,
>   Marry women of your choice, Two or three or four; but if ye fear that
>   ye shall not be able to deal justly (with them), then only one, or (a
>   captive) that your right hands possess, that will be more suitable, to
>   prevent you from doing injustice."

Al-Nisa' (3)

which mean marriages are limited up to 4.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about islam. The Question is about marrying two women at once not about the limits of marriages! Please take your time to give a well elaborated answer focused on answering the actual question read [answer].